# Alternative to complex numbers - Study numbers $j^2=1$, $j \neq 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions, roots-of-unity, clifford-algebras, split-complex-numbers

On p. 24 "Clifford Algebra and Spinors" (2.2 Double Ring of  $\:{}^2\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{R}$) by Petri Lounesto the author mentions Study numbers as an equivalent alternative to complex numbers.

The Study numbers are pair of two real numbers (a,b) $\in \mathcal{\mathbb{R}}^2$ such as
$$a+jb, \quad j^2=1 ,\quad j \neq 1$$

He introduces Study conjugate as $(a+jb)^-=a-jb$, then they can be written in hyperbolic polar form e t c.

It seems that the use of such numbers can be as powerful as the use of complex numbers then.

My questions are

- Why Study numbers are not widely known and used?
- Can someone point me to the reference to the Study numbers? I can not find it either in Wikipedia, neither in literature.

PS The mathematician is [Eduard Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Study). He approached the dual quaternions with the dual numbers.

Comment: I suppose $j\neq -1$ either

Comment: I guess so too.

Comment: I'm curious—the complex numbers were invented to solve equations such as $x^2+1=0$. How do study numbers solve this problem—what study number, when multiplied by itself, makes $-1$?

Comment: Study numbers are well known, but their ring is simply isomorphic to $\Bbb R\times R$ via $(a+bj)\mapsto(\frac{a+b}2,\,\frac{a-b}2$ and thus algebraically it doesn't bring any more information.

Comment: I mean this wouldn't be a field, in fact $(a+ja)(a-ja)=0$ so neither $a+ja$ nor (a-ja) is invertible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't heard of these being called the Study numbers; the seemingly more common name is [*split-complex numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number). Equivalently, it is the [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra) $\operatorname{Cl}_{1,0}(\mathbb R)$ of a one-dimensional real vector space with a positive-definite quadratic form.

As a real algebra, these are isomorphic to a direct product $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, thus it is hardly an interesting research subject (anything about it follows from properties of $\mathbb R$ and direct products of rings).

Comment: The article on split-complex numbers mentions that they are also referred to as study numbers, [among others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number#Synonyms).

Comment: Thank you so much! I suspected that the issue was in terminology for these numbers.

Comment: @Joe Indeed! Its weird to have that many names for such a thing.

Comment: "hardly an interesting research subject" - except maybe properties of zero divisors?

Comment: @Anixx What properties do you have in mind?

Comment: For instance, connection to Euler-Mascheroni constant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4153974/dos-the-euler-mascheroni-constant-gamma-correspond-to-infinite-hyperbolic-ang

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403344/hypermodulus-and-what-mathematical-objects-have-it