# Does the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ correspond to infinite hyperbolic angle?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant, regularization, divergent-integrals

So, I am trying to find the regularized value of the divergent integral $I=\int_1^\infty \sqrt{x^2-1}dx$. Since the area of sector of a circle $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac\pi4$, I wonder whether the area under hyperbola would be interesting as well.

So, I applied my method that uses Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_t[t f(t)](x)$ so to convert divergent integrals into equivalent ones.

This way I obtained a family of equivalent integrals:

$\int_1^\infty \sqrt{x^2-1}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{K_2(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty \left(x-\frac{1}{2 x}\right) dx =\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{2 x}\right)dx$ (here $K$ is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html)).

[image]

Now, we already know that $\int_0^\infty \frac1xdx$ regularizes to $\gamma$ while $\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^3}dx$ and $\int_0^\infty xdx$ regularize to zero, so integral $I$ regularizes to $-\frac\gamma2$.

This is a very interesting result. One also can notice that the area of the hyperbolic sector between the hyperbola and $y=x$ regularizes to $\gamma/2$ (because the area under $f(x)=x$ regularizes to zero), but we know that twice the area of the hyperbolic sector corresponds to hyperbolic angle. So, does $\gamma$ corresponds to infinite hyperbolic angle?

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/HyperbolicAnimation.gif]

P.S. The area under the conjugate hyperbola is $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x^2+1}dx=\int_0^\infty \left(x+\frac{1}{2 x}\right)dx$, which regularizes to $\gamma/2$.

Comment: What is $K_2(x)$?

Comment: @Gary this one: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html

Comment: Mention in your question that it is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: @Gary OK, done.